# How to show check box text if it is not next to check box using jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I am trying to achieve checked value text should visible like shown in the image:

[image: image here]

Without refresh or any click can anyone help me out?

This is my php dynamic from :

```
<div class="products-row">
    <?php $tq=$conn->query("select * from os_tiffen where tiffen_status=1 order by id_tiffen ASC");
        while ($tiffen = $tq->fetch_assoc()) {
        ?>  
        <div class="col-md-3"> 
            <div class="foodmenuform row text-center">
                <input multiple="multiple" type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_image']; ?>" name="tifeen" hidden>
                <label for="<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_image'];?>"><img src="img/tiffen/<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_image']; ?>" class="img img-responsive" /></label>
                <h3 class="FoodName"><?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_name'];?></h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php }  ?>
</div>
```

This is my script to show the text:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    var FoodMenu = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
        return $(this).next('.FoodName').text();
    }).get().join("<br>");
    $("#selectedfood").html(FoodMenu);
});
</script>
```

Out put id: `<a id="selectedfood"></a></li>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to get all checked options’ text on checkbox change event and append selected values to “selectedfood”. The following sample code is for your reference.

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(".foodmenuform [type='checkbox']").change(function () {

        var FoodMenu = "";
        var ischecked = $(".foodmenuform [type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {

            FoodMenu += $(this).siblings(".FoodName").text() + "<br/>";
        })

        $("#selectedfood").html(FoodMenu);
    })
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easier thank i thought:

```
var checkedFood = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(){
//console.log($('input[type=checkbox]:checked').serialize());
return $(this).val();
}).get().join("<br>");
$("#selectedfood").html(checkedFood);
```

Form:

```
<div class="products-row">
<?php $tq=$conn->query("select * from os_tiffen where tiffen_status=1 order by id_tiffen ASC");
    while ($tiffen = $tq->fetch_assoc()) {
    ?>  
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
        <div class="foodmenuform row text-center">
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $tiffen['id_tiffen'];?>" class="Foodmenu" value="<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_name'];?>" name="tifeen[]" hidden>
            <label for="<?php echo $tiffen['id_tiffen'];?>"><img src="img/tiffen/<?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_image']; ?>" class="img img-responsive" /></label>
            <h3><?php echo $tiffen['tiffen_name'];?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php }  ?>
</div>
```